# How to avoid the messy code normal when using RunProcess?

Tags: character-encoding

If I use the English words,it works well

```
RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "echo hello world"}]["StandardOutput"]
```

> "hello world"

but it has some problems when using Chinese

```
RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "echo 你好"}]["StandardOutput"]
```

> "ä½ å¥½"

I expect it to give "你好" rather than "ä½ å¥½".

Later,I try this code,it really output the right result.

```
ToCharacterCode[
  RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "echo 你好"}]["StandardOutput"]] // 
 FromCharacterCode[#, "UTF-8"] &
```

> 你好

But it gives ***error*** when doing this:

```
 ToCharacterCode[RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "date/t"}]["StandardOutput"]] //FromCharacterCode[#, "UTF-8"] &
```

In fact in cmd ,I get:
[image]

On my computer:

```
 ToCharacterCode[RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "date/t"}]["StandardOutput"]]
```

it gives

> {50, 48, 49, 54, 47, 48, 52, 47, 48, 52, 32, 214, 220, 210, 187, 32, 13, 10}

According ASCII,{50, 48, 49, 54, 47, 48, 52, 47, 48, 52, 32} means "2016/04/04 ".{214, 220, 210, 187} means "周一"

```
FromCharacterCode[{214, 220, 210, 187},"CP936"]
```

So I guess the rest part {32, 13, 10} it has no means.So it gives error.

So how to make `RunProcess` work fine for Chinese characters?

Comment: I can confirm this happens on linux as well using `RunProcess[{"echo", "你好"}]["StandardOutput"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how this works on Windows systems, but I always use `Import` to grab any output from a command-line argument:

```
Import["!echo \"hello 你好\"", "Text"]
(* "hello 你好" *)
```

Comment: Yes Import["!echo \"hello 你好\"", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"] works! ^_^

Comment: Right on!  Glad it could help, I couldn't really test it without having a similar system

Answer (score 1):

```
RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", "date/t>test.txt"}]["StandardOutput"];
Import["test.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"]
```

> > "2016/04/04 周一 "